# How do you compute the reduced SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I know how to compute the full SVD by hand, but surprisingly, I couldn't find much information on how to compute the reduced SVD by hand. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: When you say the "reduced SVD", what do you mean? Going off the [terminology here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Thin_SVD), are you looking for the "thin" SVD or the "compact" SVD?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. Exactly

Comment: The question I asked was not one with a yes/no answer

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh sorry, I only saw the first part of the link you sent. It's the "thin" SVD. It seems the procedure to compute the thin SVD is the same as computing the full SVD. I had thought there was a simplified procedure for it.

Comment: No problem. You do save a bit of effort with the compact SVD, though, since you don't need to extend your basis, that is, you don't have to extend the orthonormal eigenvectors corresponding to the non-zero singular values to produce an orthonormal basis of the nullspace

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah I see. I've never worked with the compact SVD before. In my numerical linear algebra class, I was only taught the full SVD. where to compute SVD of $A$, i.e., $A=U\Sigma V^T$ I diagonalize $A = VDV^T$, and then use $AV = U\Sigma$ to find $U$. Now I'm doing some machine learning stuff, and it seems they frequently use the thin SVD, where $\Sigma$ is defined to be square. I suppose solving $AV = U\Sigma$ could be easier for the thin SVD if $\Sigma$ is full rank because I could just do $AV\Sigma^{-1} = U$.

Comment: Yes, if $A$ (and therefore $\Sigma$) has full rank, then the thin SVD is indeed simple. Note that in this case, the thin and compact SVD's are the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most efficient way. But this method will work by hand. [From this and the theorems you learn in class, you can easily improve this method, especially in using $A^*A$ versus $AA^*$ and finding $U$).

1. Compute $A^*A$.
2. Find eigenvalues of $A^*A$, and construct $\Sigma$.
3. Find $\Sigma^{-1}$.
4. Compute the eigenvectors of $A^*A$, and construct $V$ and $V^*$ by normalizing these vectors.
5. Find $U$ via $U= AV\Sigma^{-1}$.
6. Write $A= U\Sigma V^*$.

As an example taken from my old lecture notes.

[image]

[image]

[image]